# how to fix machine learning flask app that keeps timing out on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have a flask app that is supposed to do predictions on user input, after it takes the input it uses a preloaded character level lstm model to generate 1000 characters. What I do is iterate 1000 times and predict each input with the pre-loaded model and then map the prediction into a string.

The problem is that this process takes longer than 30 seconds therefore heroku gives me a timeout error, is there any way to solve this? I have read about background processes but the page cannot move forward until the predictions have been made so I'm not sure what to do here. I will provide the code that I do to make predictions below

```
    pattern = []
    for char in input_words:
        try:
            pattern.append(self.char_to_int[char])
        except:
            pattern.append(0)
    output = ''
    #print(pattern)
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1000):
        x = np.reshape(pattern, (1, len(pattern), 1))
        x = x / float(n_vocab)
        prediction = m.predict(x, verbose=0)
        m._make_predict_function()
        index = sample(prediction)
        result = int_to_char[index]
        output = output+result

        pattern.append(index)
        pattern = pattern[1:len(pattern)]

        pattern.append(index)
        pattern = pattern[1:len(pattern)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a background process (multiprocessing.Process f.e) doing all the iterations in background. Once the prediction is finished, you store it in a variable or a database.

While the background process is running, you can periodically fetch a route of your app returning the results or the information that the results are being computed.